# There are n men and n women. Each man chooses k women and each woman chooses k men. (k is given) Woman and man meet iff both of them chose each other

Tags: probability, expected-value

There are $n$ men and $n$ women.

Each man chooses $k$ women and each woman chooses $k$ men. ($k$ is given)

Woman and man meet **iff** both of them chose each other.

Find the expected value of the meeting's number.

My solution (really not sure):

$$E[X]= \sum_{i=0}^n i {n\choose k}\Bigl(\frac{k}{n} \Bigr)^i \Bigl(1-\frac{k}{n}\Bigr)^{n-i}$$

$i$ - The number of the meetings.

$(\dfrac{k}{n})$ - The probability to choose men such that he chose the woman.

I'd be grateful for a feedback!

Comment: How many potential meetings are there? What is the probability any particular meeting happens?

Comment: You can check answers with some edge cases. If $k=0$, then $E[X]=0$. That checks out. If $k=n$, then $E[X]=n^2$. But your formula gives $E[X]=n(n-1)/2$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you got $E[X]= \sum_{i=0}^n i {n\choose k}(\frac{k}{n})^i(1-\frac{k}{n})^{n-i}$.

I especially don't understand why there is a leading factor of $i$ in the sum.

Here is how I would approach it.

Choose any man. Call him $m_1$. He likes $k$ the women $w_1,\ldots, w_k$.

**What is the probability** $\boldsymbol w_1$ **also likes him?**

The expected number of men met by $m_1$ is $k$ times that probability, since it is the same probability that each of $w_1,\ldots, w_k$ like him.

The total expected number of meetings is $n$ times THAT probability, since the total number of expected meetings is the same for each man.